# Push only one file to github

Tags: git, github

I have two remotes `origin` and `other`.
So I did:

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push origin master
```

Then I want to add one file (without `git add .` done before) to `other`.

```
git add onefile
git commit -m "message"
git push other master
```

But these commands push to `other` repository with previous addings.
How to do it without it?

Comment: If you want the two remotes to have different histories, you'd need to check them out as two different branches locally (and then commit to each separately).